# How do I change the text characteristics (e.g. size & font) of my randomly generated string out of an array?

Tags: html, css, arrays, text

I'm currently using the following code, but can't seem to find any tutorial on how to change the displayed text when someone clicks the button. (meaning for example the font/size of the text: "activity 1" / "activity 2" or "activity 3"). I'm very new to HTML, so I guess I made some huge errors on the syntax somewhere, which is why the conventional earlier stackoverflow answers don't seem to work for me. Would mean a lot if any of you could give some advise or tell me where I made the mistake! thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    const cars = ["activity 1", "activity 2", "activity 3"    ];
    var randomItem = cars[Math.floor(Math.random()*cars.length)];
    
</script>

</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button class="generate-button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 
'Try this activity to improve your experience:' + randomItem, 
randomItem = cars[Math.floor(Math.random()*cars.length)];">
    generate a fun activity:</button>
   

    <p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>

<style>

    .generate-button 
    
    {

    }
   
</style>
```

my apologies to the totally wrong formatting, I'm not experienced with stackoverflow, since this is my first post. However, when I put this code into Visual studio, it does display the exact problem i'm currently facing.

Edit 2:The current output i get, is as follows:
[my problem with the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXnUN.png)

However, I want the output, "activity 2", to be of a bigger size, and visually to be more appealing. I can however not find anywhere, how to change the visual aspects of this output that I have created. Hope this explains my question any further.

Comment: This should help you make your code into a snippet that we can run: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don’t understand what is your exact requirement. Can you pls edit your question to include the expected exact behaviour?